# tkinter window works well only in the first execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to build a tkinter window that has some Check buttons, an image, and a button. I use the Spyder IDE and the code works just fine when I open Spyder and run it for the first time. But when I try to execute again, the image doesn't appear, and also apparently the window does not get destroyed by the button I've created. Is there something wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk                              # GUI configuration
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


# Window to select the analysis actions
config_window = tk.Tk()

config = { # Dictionary with variables that control what the algorithm will do
     "EDIT_FILES":     tk.BooleanVar(),
     "RMS_ANALYSE":    tk.BooleanVar(),
     "WATERFALL_FFT":  tk.BooleanVar()
}
config_window.title('Analysis settings')

label = tk.Label(config_window, text='Please check the boxes corresponding to the operations you would like to do',\
                 background='red')
label.grid(row=0, sticky='n')

tk.Checkbutton(config_window, text='Edit the files created from the sensor measurements', \
               variable=config["EDIT_FILES"]).grid(row=1, sticky='w')
tk.Checkbutton(config_window, text='RMS analysis', \
               variable=config["RMS_ANALYSE"]).grid(row=2, sticky='w')
tk.Checkbutton(config_window, text='FFT analysis', \
               variable=config["WATERFALL_FFT"]).grid(row=3, sticky='w')

image = Image.open("logo.png").resize((220,80), Image.ANTIALIAS)
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, size=10)
im_label = tk.Label(image=logo)
im_label.image = logo
im_label.grid(row=4, sticky='w')

tk.Button(config_window, text='Ok', width=10, command=config_window.destroy).grid(row=4, sticky='e')

config_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, and it functions in regular IDLE.

From their github page it looks like this is a issue in the Anaconda backend that Spyder uses, there is an open issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7074

Comment: I tried all the solutions cited in the open issue you sent, but nothing worked for me.